# How can I extract a substring up to the first digit?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I find the first substring until I find the first digit?

Example:

```
my $string = 'AAAA_BBBB_12_13_14' ;
```

Result expected: 'AAAA_BBBB_'

Comment: Wow. Every answer so far is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from the tags you want to use a regular expression.  So let's build this up.

- We want to match from the beginning of the string so we anchor with [a `^` metacharacter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) at the beginning
- We want to match anything but digits so we [look at the character classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Using-character-classes) and find out this is `\D`
- We want 1 or more of these so we [use the `+` quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) which means 1 or more of the previous part of the pattern.

This gives us the following regular expression:

```
^\D+
```

Which we can use in code like so:

```
my $string = 'AAAA_BBBB_12_13_14';
$string =~ /^\D+/;
my $result = $&;
```

Comment: if you use : 
`/(\d)/ - regex, which search FIRST digit in string`
and after this you have $\` - var, which contain string before matching

Comment: @loldop - That method fails if the string has no digits to match as it returns a blank string rather than the whole string.

Comment: it isn't a task (find a first digit)

and if there're no digits, his program will do something else:

`$str =~ /(\d)/ and foo($\`) or foo2();`

Comment: You have a couple problem here. First, Perl only sets the match variables on a successful match, so you need to check the result of the match operator so you don't get left over values from previous matches. Second, the `$&` is going to slow down all your matches with it's very well known performance issue. You don't need it here. Just use a capture.

Answer (score 2):

Most people got half of the answer right, but they missed several key points.

- You can only trust the match variables after a successful match. Don't use them unless you know you had a successful match.
- The `$&`, ``` $``, and ```$'` have well known performance penalties across all regexes in your program.
- You need to anchor the match to the beginning of the string. Since Perl now has user-settable default match flags, you want to stay away from the `^` beginning of line anchor. The `\A` beginning of string anchor won't change what it does even with default flags.

This would work:

```
my $substring = $string =~ m/\A(\D+)/ ? $1 : undef;
```

If you really wanted to use something like `$&`, use Perl 5.10's per-match version instead. The `/p` switch provides non-global-perfomance-sucking versions:

```
my $substring = $string =~ m/\A\D+/p ? ${^MATCH} : undef;
```

If you're worried about what might be in `\D`, you can specify the character class yourself instead of using the shortcut:

```
my $substring = $string =~ m/\A[^0-9]+/p ? ${^MATCH} : undef;
```

I don't particularly like the conditional operator here, so I would probably use the match in list context:

```
my( $substring ) = $string =~ m/\A([^0-9]+)/;
```

If there must be a number in the string (so, you don't match an entire string that has no digits, you can throw in a lookahead, which won't be part of the capture:

```
my( $substring ) = $string =~ m/\A([^0-9]+)(?=[0-9])/;
```

Comment: I kinda like `/\A(\D*)/ && $1` myself. Don’t see why to bother with a `/(pat)/ ? $1 : undef` most of the time, given that `&& $1` is usually good enough.  People don’t use `&&` as much for its string potential as they could.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $str =~ /(\d)/; print $`;
```

This code print string, which stand before matching

Comment: This doesn't work if the string has no digits in it.  For example if `$string = 'AAAA_BBBB'` I would expect `'AAAA_BBBB'` to be returned but this returns an empty string as there is no digit to match.

Comment: `$str=~/(\d)/ and print $\` or print $str;`

Comment: You have a couple problem here. First, Perl only sets the match variables on a successful match, so you need to check the result of the match operator so you don't get left over values from previous matches. Second, the $` is going to slow down all your matches with it's very well known performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le '$string=q(AAAA_BBBB_12_13_14);$string=~m{(\D+)} and print $1'
AAAA_BBBB_
```

Comment: You need to anchor that match so you start from the beginning of the string instead of perhaps matching non-digits after the first digit.